# Design Using Gimp

Tags: gimp, layers

A gimp newbie. Does anyone know any tutorial that I can use to create an image like this?

[image]

Comment: Hello @Ouya, welcome to GDSE. We're here to help designers with issues they might run across. Complete tutorials are a bit out of scope though, there are other places on the web better suited for that. Please refer to [how to ask](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. Some terms you might want to google to find applicable tutorials: _clipping mask_, _masking a layer_.

Comment: The same question for Photoshop: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/71543/52050

Comment: If you need some Gimp hand-holding, check out http://gimpforums.com/ (mods, please remove if you think this is out of scope, even though PieBie's answer makes me think this can be useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gimp:

- Open the texture picture
- Use *File>Open as layers* to open a the lion picture as a new layer
- Scale/move the lion layer
- Use one of the selection tools to make a selection following the shape of the lion (this is indeed the hard part... the adequate tools depends a lot on the lion's picture, this can take from a couple of seconds to a god half hour)
- Hide the lion layer, select the texture layer
- *Select>Invert* to select the layer outside of the lion
- *Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel* if you want something different from the default background
- *Edit>Clear* to delete the selected area.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact way to do this in gimp but in Photoshop this is not that hard.

What you need here are two pictures (obviously).
For example

- a picture of an apple
- a picture of the sea

If you want the apple to have the "texture" of the sea picture, all you have to do is selecting the entire outline of the apple and create a *clipping mask* using that selection you just made and the picture of the sea.

Normally the picture of the new "texture" has to be below the mask.
So in this case your layer order would have to be:

- Layer 1 Apple (I am a clipping mask now mom!)
- Layer 0 Sea (I am providing the texture now :D)

Tip: If you plan to use more than those 2 layers in your document, I recommend to merge those layers as soon as youre done. Clipping masks can get confusing pretty quick if you don't know exactly what you're doing and don't take care of them soon enough by merging them into something "normal".