# Mask Gray in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, mask

I want to make everything that is 50% Gray in Photoshop trasnaprent.
Black and White should be 100%, but all in the middle transparent.

Let's compare these to images to demonstrate:

*Start*:

[image]

*Goal*:

[image]

*Yes the checkerboard is part of the image in order to illustrate which effect I want to accomplish*

I would like to do it mathematically exact, rather than faking it.

Comment: What have you attempted, yourself? Is this being applied to an existing image, or will it always be as linear as you have above? Also, I suspect you have your wording slightly wrong and mean everything that is 50% grey should be *transparent*.

Comment: The problem is that in your goal you didn't remove only 50% gray. That would leave a stripe in the middle transparent as next to it you would have 49% and 51%. What I think you want is to select > color range  and blend form the colour you want to mask/delete.

Comment: It is good to remember that monitor color is not linear!

Comment: I just want to know how I can make gray opaque. @SZCZERZOKŁY. Thanks, u r correct it is more of an masking than removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a video showing this very thing for [another question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76178/how-to-superimpose-image-on-all-dark-areas-of-another-image), here it is at the relevant starting point: https://youtu.be/F6IhXVxBSQM?t=5m36s

Going off your image:

- Middle Gray is 128, 128, 128
- 1 stop Lighter is 191, 191, 191
- 1 stop Darker is 64, 64, 64

So adjust the Blend If slider accordingly:

[image]

[image]

If you want it to look more like your "Goal" though it's not actually only removing 50% than adjust the sliders to your liking.

Comment: 128 to 255 white
0 to 127 black
would be correct I guess. But it does not leave the black and whites untouched. And in your example, the dark gray is still 100%.

Comment: @Type-Style huh? You only wanted the 50% gray removed according to your question so I don't understand your comment. What are you wanting?

Comment: I am sorry, 0/127 for white and 12/255 for black in the sliders works fine. I wanted only the #000 and #fff to be untouched. Everything in between gets more and more transparent, the closer it gets to gray.