# Blending images in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

How I can achieve this effect in Photoshop? With what keywords I can search on Google?

[image: Man-suit-construction]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make this image in image effect?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/71543/how-do-i-make-this-image-in-image-effect)

Comment: This is called a Double Exposure. If you search that, you'll find loads of tutorials

Comment: Yes, I appreciate @AshleePalka, There are many double exposure tutorials on YouTube, and they have all made it seem so easy that it's really easy to find out what to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to achieve this, but here's a quick and easy one that works...

1. Place your city scape / scenery on the base layer.
2. Place your image of the dude in the suit on the layer above.
3. Change the blending mode of that layer to SCREEN.

This will only work if your image of the man in the suit has a perfect white background, otherwise you may have to do some tidying up of the outer areas.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris. I only thought of opacity. I think the blending of "Hard Light" is better for my images... Good morning

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is known as double exposure. There's dozens of tutorials on Youtube about this kind of effect. Like this one: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=pMMOnwCP4Ik